# Batch: how to loop a command with X number of inputs and automate each input

Tags: batch-file, scripting, window, user-input

I have a command in batch that will produce X number of inputs depending on files that were changed that will take Yes or No:

```
tf undo * /recursive
```

Normally, to automate input into a batch script, you would do:

```
echo No | tf undo * /recursive
or
(echo No && echo No) | tf undo * /recursive
```

But the above only works for a finite amount of inputs. Is there a way to enter No in all the input prompts automatically?

tf is a command for TFS. Documentation on the command used here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/undo-command?view=azure-devops

Comment: Do you have more code you are not sharing with us? I have ideas, but want to see how you are actually outputting the X number of files

Comment: That's pretty much it. When you run `tf undo * /recursive`, it outputs a series of prompts that ask: "Do you want to undo changes to file Y(Yes/No/All):"

Comment: Is this a windows batch file? Windows does not have a built-in `tf` command, therefore you need to tell us something about it at least so we know how this `yes/no/all` prompting works

Comment: Yea, this is batch. tf is a command for TFS. I updated my question to include the command information. Thank you.

Comment: The link you gave mentions a `/noprompt` switch (at a very prominent spot). I won't download and install just to try, but it sounds quite promising.

Comment: /noprompt would automatically answer all. So if I did `tf undo * /recursive /noprompt`, it will undo all my changes without the `Yes/No/All` prompt.